# Performance testing tornado application

Tags: performance, tornado

What are the best possible tools for testing tornado application performance ?
I know Apache benchmark is one way to do performance testing.
Could anyone suggest me a tool, which is easy to use...

Comment: Is "Easy to use" your only requirement? "Free", "powerful", "scalable", "information rich" may also be important...

Answer (score 2):

I've run tests on python frameworks with [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) it gives a little more control than ab. I recommend trying it.

Others popular ones are [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) (as you mentioned) and [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

[Gatling](http://gatling.io/#/) is a benchmarking tool I've been exposed to and seemed easy enough to use.

There's also [Yahoo Cloud Service Benchmark](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB) which is in Java. The time to get up and running was longer than with gatling but once you get it running it's very powerful.